# Does ice pack therapy have any healing effect for a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, cryotherapy

When suffering from a tendinopathy, ice pack therapy reliefs pains. Does it have any healing effect as well?

Comment: Have you tried DMSO or MSM?

Comment: @kenorb Thanks for the pointers. I haven't. According to https://runnersconnect.net/running-injury-prevention/dmso-treatment-running-injuries/, DMSO has unfortunately no positive effect. http://www.livestrong.com/article/502952-dmso-tendonitis/ is more optimistic. I couldn't find much to the regarding the use of methylsulfonylmethane for tendon injuries. For both DMSO and MSM, there might be some temporary relief, but unsure about long-term healing effect.

Comment: I think there are different opinions, e.g. [here](http://www.dailymile.com/blog/health/dmso-the-best-injury-treatment-youve-never-heard-of) and [here](https://www.sott.net/article/228453-DMSO-The-Real-Miracle-Solution), but anyway, it was worth to share.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in [this answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/254/26), icing is not meant to heal tendinopathy. It is supposed to be a painkiller. It can have some effects that may feel like they are fixing the problem though. The cold ice forces blood vessels to contract which can help reduce the inflammation. This might be considered healing, but the tendinopathy is still there, until the tendon heals itself.